# Cayley-Hamilton proof using linear discrete-time systems

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof, control-theory, cayley-hamilton

So I had a question regarding proving the Cayley-Hamilton theorem using discrete states i.e.
$x(k+1)=Ax(k)+bu(k)$ & $y(k)=c^Tx(k)$ where $x(k),b,c \in R^n$.
The question stated that for an integer n and real numbers $a_0, a_1,..a_n$ we define an input sequence $u(k)$  s.t  $u(0)=a_0, u(-1)=a_1,..., u(-n)=a_n$ and another condition to solve the problem is that $x(-n)=0$

And in order to shorten the question, we define the characteristic polynomial of $a(z)$ as $a(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z_1+a_0$.

The first section was to prove that $x(1)=a(A)b$ which was pretty straight-forward and the second section was to find an expression for $y(1)$ using the first question which came as $y(1)=c^Ta(A)b$.

The section I had an issue with was proving that $y(1)=0$

For this section we defined the Z-transform of the sequences in question i.e. $y(k), x(k)$ and $u(k)$.

Without showing much of the derivation as I don't feel it relevant to the question, (I can add it below if deemed necessary) I obtained,  $U(z)=a(z), (zI-A)X(Z)=U(z)$ $Y(z)=c^T(zI-A)^{-1}bU(z)=c^T(zI-A)^{-1}ba(z)$. For A inveritble, I had no problem in showing that $y(1)=0$ because I plugged in $z=0$ into the Z transform and I obtained $Y(0)=-c^TA^-1ba_0=-c^TA^-1b\cdot det(A)$ which is non-zero and because of that we know that we don't have a pole at zero and that means the ROC contains $|z|=0$ and thus the system is anti-causal. As a result, $y(k)=0$ for $k>0$ and thus $y(1)=0$.

This isn't enough though as the Cayley-Hamilton theorem holds for all square matrices so I necessarily have to show it for A that's non-invertible.

I'm not sure how to go about this as I'm not too well versed in proving such items mathematically or rigorously but a push in what approach to adopt to solve it for the non-invertible A case would really help.

update:
So I was informed that the logic of considering the value of $Y(0)$ and checking if $Y(0)$ is finite doesn't hold with the following counter-example $\sum_{i=0}^\infty az^{-1}=F(z):=z/(z-a)$ for $z=0, F(0)=0$ but the ROC is $|z|>a$ which doesn't contain $|z|=0$. I did manage to expand $(zI-A)^-1$ into a power series but there may be more information needed to complete the proof.

Comment: Do you have a link to this exercise? Seems like some things are missing.

Comment: Can I give a google drive link with the exercise inside the drive?

Comment: Yes, you can try.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Q4GyDBK3HaJoKNASiDGUz7qWZAvZ1KS-?usp=sharing I clearly retracted some things for the brevity of the question but if need be I'll edit the question to be all-inclusive. The question is Q5 in the PDF

Comment: I do not get your anticausal discussion part but what I would do is expand express $(zI−A)^{-1}$ in a power series and check the series for $Y(z)$.

Comment: I do not think your "proof" is also correct as you cannot typically evaluate the region of convergence by evaluating the transfer function at a certain point as the transfer function can be analytically continued to a larger domain. Typically, the whole complex plane except at the eigenvalues of $A$, at least.

Comment: The power series idea was actually helpful and I derived certain relations that may be truthful but they do rely on the "proof" that you pointed out as incorrect. What I did in the proof was simply check for any poles at zero as poles are the regions where $Y(z)$ wouldn't converge. So no pole at zero means we don't know the entire ROC but we know that at the very least 0 is inside the ROC. I don't evaluate the ROC in its entirety, I just check if it diverges at a certain point in order to classify the said point as a pole or not.

Comment: No, the it is not because the function is finite at some point that this point lies within the ROC. You are confusing the ROC and the extended domain of the limit function. For instance, let $\sum_{i=0}^\infty az^{-1}=F(z):=z/(z-a)$, $a>0$. Clearly, $F(0)=0$. However, zero does not belong to the ROC which is given by $|z|>a$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145136/discussion-between-user626-and-kbs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually much simpler. As usual, when a problem is approached from the right angle, the solution becomes natural.

Consider the input

$$
u:\{-n,\ldots\}\mapsto\{a_n,\ldots,a_1,a_0,0,\ldots\}
$$
and the initial condition $x(-n)=0$. We know already that $x(1)=a(A)b$ and, hence, that $y(1)=c^Ta(A)b$. To see that $y(1)=0$, note first that the $z$-transform of the sequence $u$ is given by

$$
U(z)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iz^i=a(z)=\det(zI-A).
$$

Therefore, we have that

$$
Y(z)=H(z)U(z)=N(z)
$$
where $H(z):=c^T(zI-A)^{-1}b=:N(z)/a(z)$, where $N(z)$ is the numerator of the transfer function associated with $(A,b,c^T)$. For completeness, the the numerator is given by

$$
N(z):=\begin{bmatrix}
zI-A & b\\c^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now, since there is no direct feedthrough (i.e. the output $y$ does not depend directly on the input $u$), the degree of $N(z)$ is at most $n-1$ and, we have that

$$
Y(z)=\alpha_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+\alpha_{1}z+\alpha_{0}.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
Y(z)=y(-n+1)z^{n-1}+\ldots+y(-1)z+y(0)+y(1)z^{-1}+y(2)z^{-2}+\ldots,
$$
which implies that $y(k)=0$ for all $k\ge1$.

Now, it is enough to observe that this holds regardless of the value for $b$ and $c$, which means that $c^Ta(A)b=0$ for all $b,c\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This implies that we necessarily have that $a(A)=0$.

Comment: when you talk of "no direct feedthrough"what's the relation between that and $N(z)$ having a degree of at most $n-1$? I ask this because direct feedthrough refers to $y(t)$ relying on $y(t)$ in an algebraic loop as far as I've seen. Maybe there's a different concept to it?

Comment: A direct feedthrough is when the output depends directly on the input, which is not the case here. The presence of an algebraic loop is another issue of systems in feedback loop. This is not relevant in the current situation. It is easy to prove that if the numerator has degree $n$, then there is a nonzero direct feedthrough term. Since there is not such term here. this means that the degree of the numerator is at most $n-1$.

Comment: I undestand the direct feed through argument. My next clarification is, the direct feedthrough term would contribute to the $z^n$ term then yes? is $N(z)$ at most degree $n-1$ because it would rely on the remaining n samples of $u(k)$ from $0$ to $-(n-1)?$ and is it also at most degree $n-1$ because $u(k)$ is anti-causal and it might be different if u were causal? I'm just trying to clarify the problem for myself as much as possible

Comment: I have already explained the relationship between a nonzero direct feedthrough and the term in $z^n$ in my previous comment. Note also that the numerator $N(z)$ is independent of the input, which should answer all your questions regarding this point.  Indeed, the numerator depends on the system $(A,b,c^T)$ only. I have added some details.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications and the answer! made more sense after brushing up on some concepts that weren't clear and revisting the answer you submitted.